# Disable input field autofill (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

Does anyone know how to disable input autofill/autocomplete in **2021** using pure JS?

I've tried:

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="password" autofill="off" />
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
<input type="password" autofill="none" />
```

**etc.**

Also tried using ***jquery.disable-autofill*** and ***npm disableautofill*** from the stackoverflow solutions

Gonna be good if someone can share some more solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one more thing we can use autocomplete in form tag also like see below

```
<form action="/form/submit" method="get" autocomplete="off">
```

Or In JS

```
    $(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("input").val("");
      }, 500);
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This Solution in JS**

```js
clearAutoFIll();

function clearAutoFIll(){
  var inp = document.querySelectorAll("[autocomplete=off] input");
  for(var x=0; x < inp.length; x++){
    inp[x].value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete=off>
  <input type=text name="phone" />
</form>
```